# What Android USB driver can I use to communicate with a device that implemented WinUSB.sys

Tags: android, usb, winusb

I am about to write an Android application that will communicate with a device through USB. The device has implemented WinUSB.sys. 
Is there any ready made USB lib that I can use in order to avoid writing my own USB driver for Android?

I haven't got a hold of the actual device yet, so it might be that I will be able to communicate via the built in Android USB lib. If that is the case, I will let you know.